# Looking for dynamic control while rendering data using Dynamic Jasper

Tags: jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I am looking for dynamically control the rendering of data using dyanmicJasper. Basically, I want to know what is the page space left when a set of data is already rendered, how much more data can go in the report. This all is required as I have following requirements :-
- I do not want my total row as a only row on the page
- I will have footnotes which might occupy space on the bottom so need to know how much more can be rendered.

In addition I am also looking for
-I want to have different page size for odd and even page

Kindly let me know if dynamic jasper provides that level of control and if yes, how will I achive it or workaround for the same.

Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: @pankajv: If you don't get an answer here, try asking at JasperForge.

Answer (score 0):

In advance, the answer is "NO".

If JasperReports can handle, then DynamicJasper can handle (maybe with some work), but in this case I think JasperReport does not provide such features.

DJ cannot do what JR even cant.

Regards.
Dj

Comment: Hi DJ, I came across some methods like given below  
public void beforeReportInit() Called before report initialization.    
public void afterReportInit() Called after report initialization.    
public void beforePageInit() Called before each page is initialized.    
public void afterPageInit() Called after each page is initialized.    
public void beforeColumnInit() Called before each column is initialized.    
public void afterColumnInit() Called after each column is initialized.    
  
.Do we have implementation of same in dyanamic Jasper and will it suffice my need..Any Thoughts?